# replacing dictionary values into a dataframe

Tags: pandas

I have the following `df` on one side:

```
          ACCOR SA  ADMIRAL  ADECCO  BANKIA  BANKINTER
ADMIRAL         0        0       0       0          0
ADECCO          0        0       0       0          0
BANKIA          0        0       0       0          0
```

and the following `dict` on the other:

```
{'ADMIRAL': 1, 'ADECCO': -1, 'BANKIA': -1}
```

where the `df.index` values correspond to the the `dict.keys`

I would like to replace the `dict.values` into the `df` placing one value per row to obtain this output:

```
          ACCOR SA  ADMIRAL  ADECCO  BANKIA  BANKINTER
ADMIRAL         0        1       0       0          0
ADECCO          0        0      -1       0          0
BANKIA          0        0       0      -1          0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop by dict values and set values by [`at`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.at.html):

```
d = {'ADMIRAL': 1, 'ADECCO': -1, 'BANKIA': -1}

for k, v in d.items():
    df.at[k, k] = v
    #alternative
    #df.loc[k, k] = v
print (df)
         ACCOR SA  ADMIRAL  ADECCO  BANKIA  BANKINTER
ADMIRAL         0        1       0       0          0
ADECCO          0        0      -1       0          0
BANKIA          0        0       0      -1          0
```

---

Another solution is create `DataFrame` by `dict` by [`MultiIndex.from_arrays`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.MultiIndex.from_arrays.html) and [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
s = pd.Series(list(d.values()), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([d.keys(), d.keys()]))
df1 = s.unstack()
print (df1)
         ADECCO  ADMIRAL  BANKIA
ADECCO     -1.0      NaN     NaN
ADMIRAL     NaN      1.0     NaN
BANKIA      NaN      NaN    -1.0
```

And then replace non `NaN`s by [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
df = df1.combine_first(df)
print (df)
         ACCOR SA  ADECCO  ADMIRAL  BANKIA  BANKINTER
ADECCO        0.0    -1.0      0.0     0.0        0.0
ADMIRAL       0.0     0.0      1.0     0.0        0.0
BANKIA        0.0     0.0      0.0    -1.0        0.0
```

Comment: @pyd - Thank you.